# Is there a distance on $\mathbb{R}$ with this property? (compactness)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces, compactness

> Let $d$ be the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$. i.e $d(x,y) = |x-y|$. Is there a distance $d'$ with $d'(x,y) \geq d(x,y)$ so that $(\mathbb{R},d')$ is compact?

Is my proof correct?
Let $B_{\epsilon}^{d'}(x)$ denote a ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered on $x$ with respect to $d'$.

**My attempt:**

Assume such a $d'$ exists. Since $(\mathbb{R},d')$ is compact it is totally bounded. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Then there is an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\cup^{n}_{i=i}B_{\epsilon}^{d'}(x_{i}) = \mathbb{R}$. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $d'(x,x_{i}) < \epsilon$ for some $i = 1,...,n$. But
$$d(x,x_{i}) \leq d'(x,x_{i}) < \epsilon.$$ So $x \in B_{\epsilon}^{d}(x_{i}) \subset B_{\epsilon}^{d'}(x_{i}) \forall i = 1,...,n$. So $x\in \cup_{i=1}^{n}B_{\epsilon}^{d}(x_{i})$ That is $\mathbb{R} \subset \cup_{i=1}^{n}B_{\epsilon}^{d}(x_{i})$ But $\cup_{i=1}^{n}B_{\epsilon}^{d}(x_{i}) \subset \mathbb{R}$ as in we have $\cup_{i=1}^{n}B_{\epsilon}^{d}(x_{i}) = \mathbb{R}$. So $(\mathbb{R},d)$ is totally bounded which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct, *assuming* that $(\mathbb{R},d)$ isn't totally bounded. Do you know how to prove that?

Comment: Isn't that trivial?

Comment: If you assume $(\mathbb{R},d)$ is totally bounded this would imply that it is also bounded which is a contradiction.

Comment: @pureundersgrad Correct! But then you can simply say that if $(\mathbb{R},d')$ was compact, then it would be bounded and then $(\mathbb{R},d)$ would be bounded too, thereby getting a contradiction in a more simple way.

Answer (score 2):

Well your proof is correct but it could be shortened as follow:

> Indeed,  if such metric exists we have that the $Id:(\Bbb R, d')\to(\Bbb R, d)$ is continuous   since we assume  $$d(x,y)\le d'(x,y)$$
>   Then $(\Bbb R, d)= Id((\Bbb R, d'))$ is also compact as  continuous image of compact set. **However, it is well known that $(\Bbb R, d)$ is not compact.**

Comment: The OP wants to know if his proof is correct, not if the result is true.

Comment: Are you sure the identity is continuous? You cannot assume that without proof

Comment: Yes, but this is a very easy answer. Much easier than what the OP did.

Comment: @DuncanRamage I just give a easiest way to OP see the edit

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is "is my proof correct." You should answer that question, and may also include a simpler proof if you wish. But you haven't answered the question.

Comment: @Math_QED is there any problem with easier proof?.

Comment: I've changed my vote with the edit.

Comment: @GuyFsone I don't know, probably because someone else downvoted your answer. I cannot tell you why they did so.

Comment: Why must that identity be continuous if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: No I defended your answer. I always appreciate short approaches. And in case you wondered I upvoted.

Comment: @pureundersgrad Standard epsilon-delta proof. Let $\varepsilon > 0$, and let $\delta = \varepsilon$. Then, if $d'(x, y) < \delta = \varepsilon$, we have that $d(f(x), f(y)) = d(x, y) < d'(x, y) < \varepsilon$, so the identity is continuous.

Comment: @pureundersgrad it is continuous because  $d(x,y)\le d'(x,y)$ see the edit: Now take any converging sequence for $d'$ automatically converges for $d$ that is exactly the continuity

Comment: @pureundersgrad see the comment by Duncan Ramage

Comment: Oh that was trivial, thank you guys